# Across and down? Who needs those?

Tags: crosswords

[image]

1. One you raise as your own
2. U.S. damming org.
3. Norwich area
4. Tartan
5. Aerial lift
6. Paracetamol and emotional support, for example
7. BSN, in some schools
8. Vampire of film
9. Written-works journal of JHU
10. Borrow and get rid of
11. Ireland
12. Break down
13. Vietnam neighbor
14. Egglike
15. Do away with
16. Howdy!
17. Space org.
18. Unpolished
19. Approximately
20. Berners-Lee, among others
21. _ amis
22. Bankruptcy alternative: abbr.
23. Logger leftovers
24. Oscars
25. Apple tools
26. Dirt
27. Dirt
28. Spartans' home: abbr.
29. Currency of either of two Asian countries
30. An Islam division
31. Labor danger research org.
32. Moon moons
33. Womb
34. Sanders, for one
35. A Greek ship
36. A cotton product
37. Ad majorem _ gloriam
38. Renew
39. E, to a ham
40. Mary's girdle, for example
41. Cherub, perhaps: var.
42. Mayday
43. Dressed for winter, in a way
44. Gamelan instrument
45. Click beetle genus
46. Currency of either of two Asian countries
47. Show aired "from N.Y."
48. UAE hospital
49. A seabird
50. U.S. welfare org.
51. A bit of purchase
52. Central line terminus
53. Anonymous John
54. Him, to Pierre
55. Susceptible to coaxing
56. Question in reply to "Is that you?"
57. Choose
58. Four-legged competition
59. God of lust
60. Ohm's and Murphy's, among others
61. Faux _
62. John Paul Ⅱ shooter
63. New Haven student
64. Saudi, for example
65. Tour
66. Cambridge org. founded by G. H. Hardy
67. Boris Johnson's alma mater
68. _ roll
69. Written-works magazine of UNI
70. Hood
71. Tron manufacturer
72. Unexpected wrestler
73. _ quam videri
74. Wows
75. Peter the Great, for example

Comment: Feedback would be most welcome (I guess preferably in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

The gimmick is that

> each of the clues that would correspond to both Across and Down clues the two entries *combined*. For instance, the answer to 1 is STEPSON; STEP is entered across, and SON is entered down.
>  (Sometimes they don't make words: TREES/TUMPS in particular doesn't, and TEMP/TABLE also doesn't split 'correctly'.)

Clue answers:

> [image]

Comment: [E is correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siter) in 44 :)

Comment: @jafe Ah, thanks! Will fix.

Comment: Of course Deus solved it first